# Style Sheet Loading Issues

Tags: css, caching, stylesheet, concrete5

Whenever I save changes to my external style sheet ('view.css'), the changes do not get pushed to the web page that I am attempting to test (http://www.ryan-taylor.me/portfolio/software/american-century/) in Chrome. Things that I have tried:

1. Cleared my browser's cache
2. Cleared Concrete5's cache
3. Spammed f5 for hopeful refreshes
4. Tested within a different browser (IE and FireFox)
5. Used the CSS Reloader extension within Chrome to "force refresh" the the web page's style sheets

[image]

---

[image]

All the above failed to push any of the CSS changes that I made (refer to the attached photos for code visuals). The only action that does work is if I change the name of the style sheet. However, due to the fact that I do regular testing and CSS updates, I would prefer not to have to manually change the file name and the PHP call to that file each time I alter the code.

The page is still loading an older version of 'view.css'. It seems as though the style sheet is getting cached somewhere, but I'm not sure where. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is occurring and/or any solutions that I could try?

Comment: has the version changed when you edit css, and push ?

Comment: @karthikr Where can I find the version number? Are you talking about Concrete5's version punch on each page?

Comment: No - the `?v=<>` part

Comment: Looking at the site, it looks like this is working now.  Did you figure out your problem?  If so, you may wish to share your solution.

Comment: No, it still has yet to push my CSS changes.

Comment: But I can see them when I inspect the link you sent and open the developer tool; I see table/table-cell additions you made;  you can see them here: [link](http://www.ryan-taylor.me/blocks/portfolioitem/view.css?v=be39f7fef4109393d6018529282e6c14).

Comment: @tofraser I apologize for the confusion. When I checked it after your first response, I saw no new load. After recently checking again, I saw that it had pushed changes through. Bare with me on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you perhaps set your cache-control or something with meta tags?

Maybe you could give this fix a try:

[Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Consider updating your answer to include a brief summary as well, so it is still useful to others if that link changes or breaks.

Comment: I checked my cache settings and turned off all cache properties through Concrete. I also added the suggested meta tags. Still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the previous feedback and sorry for the late response. The fix to this issue seemed to have come early this morning/late last night after going to bed, but I wasn't 100% sure which of my tweaks actually solved the problem.

After retracing my steps, it seems as though **disabling Cloudflare** was the golden ticket. I completely forgot that I enabled this service for my site back in the day. It essentially caches JS and CSS on its content delivery network, acting as a performance enhancer for page loading. Considering that I'm only running a simple portfolio site here, the service wasn't doing a whole lot for me in the first place.

After disabling Cloudflare, there seemed to be a delay in the response time of it turning off and me seeing results (which is why I didn't see a change until this morning). After doing a few checks to for validation, I can confirm this was the problem child. All is well now! I hope this helps others whom may be in the same boat.

Cheers!